# code working well when i put a breakpoint on getresponsedata, but without a breakpoint it does not work

Tags: c#

```
    //webservice connection
 CRB_WEBSERVICE.CBS_SERVICE.BatchPublicServiceClient proxy = new CRB_WEBSERVICE.CBS_SERVICE.BatchPublicServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IBatchPublicService");
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
                    proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
                    string currdte = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    //Open Connection for webservice
                    proxy.Open();
    //batchid is a string requested in format the client wants
                    string batchid = "" + currdte + "_" + "D" + "_" + "**" + "_" + num + "_" + "XML" + "_" + "T"; 
//generatexml is generating an XML file which is then zipped and sent via //webservice
                    GenerateXML(batchid);
     try
                        {
//process to send zipped file via webservice

                            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(batchid + ".zip");
                                     proxy.Begin(batchid);
                            proxy.PutData(batchid, 1, data);
                            proxy.Finish(batchid, 1);
                            var b = proxy.GetBatchInfo(batchid);
                          // thread so it waits for the response
                            Thread.Sleep(11000);
// this is where my issue is.if i put a breakpoint i get a response of a //zipped file. if i dont nothing happens
                           **var result = proxy.GetResponseData(batchid, 1);**
                            //Thread.Sleep(100);
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\CBS_WEBSERVICE\Response.zip", result);
```

}

**Please note this is not the whole code.** I need assistance as my code is running perfectly when I put a breakpoint on the `GetResponseData` but if I do not it does not bring a response. I tried adding thread.sleep so it waits for a response from the webservice but still no luck. I have added comments.

Comment: How can we possibly help without knowing what any of this code is? What is `proxy`? What is `batchid`? What does `GetResponseData` do? Why are you doing `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills not sure how to paste the whole code as it is connecting to a webservice which then brings a response to my machine. let me try and repost the error

Comment: @MarkusDeibel  i have added more code and explained. does it make sense now

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to check the first parameter: `BatchStatus` before calling the method `GetDataResponse`. I read the documentation of the API again. Without the `batchstatus` `GetDataResponse` will be null hence code was hanging in release mode and only working in debug mode.

```
 var b = proxy.GetBatchInfo(batchid);

 while (b.BatchStatus != CRB_WEBSERVICE.CBS_SERVICE.BatchStatuses.Finished)
                        {
                            b = proxy.GetBatchInfo(batchid);
                        }
if (b.BatchStatus == CRB_WEBSERVICE.CBS_SERVICE.BatchStatuses.Finished)
                        {
                            if (b.BatchResult == CRB_WEBSERVICE.CBS_SERVICE.BatchResults.Success)
                            {  
                                var result = proxy.GetResponseData(batchid, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use bold formatting for everything; just for important words or phrases.